# is there a way to send SelectList in view data with int & string (in Edit function)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using Asp.net core coding a web application, I've tried to edit an item before by the default editing function in the controller with no problem.

recently I've changed an odd field in the list in index view to a select list instead of a regular view.

after that, when I tried to edit a raw it opened the editing page then when I clicked on the save button, an error message ("**InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.**") appeared.

**Save Button at Edit View:**

'''

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
```

**GET Edit Function:**

'''

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {

        List<Status>  StatusList = _context.Status.ToList();
        ViewData["StatusList"] = new SelectList(StatusList, "STID", "Name");

        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var bugsSummary = await _context.BugsSummary.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (bugsSummary == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", bugsSummary.UserId);
        ViewData["ProjectsPId"] = new SelectList(_context.Projects, "PId", "PName", bugsSummary.ProjectsPId);

        return View(bugsSummary);
    }
```

'''

I've set a breakpoint in the post edit function it doesn't enter the post edit.

I've tried to send the status ViewData in StatusList as (int, string), but the SelectList class doesn't allow.

how can I solve the InvalidCastException error?

**additional attachments:**

**HTTP POST EDIT FUNC.**

'''

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, 
 [Bind("Id,ProjectsPId,Bug,BugSummary,TesterName,ImageUrl,StatusSTID")] 
 BugsSummary bugsSummary, IFormFile myfile)
    {
        if (id != bugsSummary.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {


                //bugsSummary.ImageUrl = "";
                bugsSummary.ImageUrl = await UserFile.UploadeNewImageAsync(bugsSummary.ImageUrl,
          myfile, _environment.WebRootPath, Properties.Resources.ImgFolder, 100, 100);

                bugsSummary.PublicationDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
                bugsSummary.UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);


                _context.Update(bugsSummary);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BugsSummaryExists(bugsSummary.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["UserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", bugsSummary.UserId);
        ViewData["ProjectsPId"] = new SelectList(_context.Projects, "PId", "PName", bugsSummary.ProjectsPId);

        return View(bugsSummary);
    }
```

'''

**Form:**

'''

```
<form asp-action="Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />


        <div class="form-group">

            <label asp-for="ProjectsPId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ProjectsPId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ProjectsPId" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>


        <input type="hidden" asp-for="UserId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Bug" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Bug" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Bug" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BugSummary" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="BugSummary" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="BugSummary" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TesterName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="TesterName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TesterName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ImageUrl" class="control-label"></label>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/" + AkelTestingTool.Properties.Resources.ImgFolder + "/" + Model.ImageUrl)" width="150" height="90" />

            <input type="file" name="myfile" id="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input asp-for="ImageUrl" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ImageUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <label asp-for="Status.Name" class="control-label"></label>

        @foreach (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem status in ViewBag.StatusList as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectList)
        {
            if (int.Parse(status.Value) == Model.StatusSTID)
            {
                status.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                status.Selected = false;
            }
        }
        

        <div class="from-group">

            <select asp-for="Status.Name" asp-items="@(ViewBag.StatusList)"></select>

            @* <select asp-for="StatusSTID" asp-items="ViewBag.StatusList","Name" ></select> *@


            <span asp-validation-for="Status.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">


            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />

        </div>

    </form>
```

'''

Comment: what does the form contain? the action result will try to bind the form values to the same type as the parameters in the actionresult

Comment: In order for anyone to give advice I'd say you should post (a) the form code and (b) the `Edit` `HttpPost` method in addition to what you have posted.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post.
Waiting for your answers.
Thanks

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the action result binds the form values to the same type as the parameters in the action result, I've checked all the values it is the same, I don't know what is the int parameter that it can't convert it to string, I tried to remove all the parameters, it shows the same error, I've posted the other codes, thanks all.